# X Window Terminates when I type {+<ENTER>

Tags: fedora, xorg, kde

In particular when I type the following keyboard combo:

`<hold shift> [ <release shift> <enter>`

I get dumped out of KDE and see a flash of some console output but I can't find it in any log.

I'm running Fedora 15 (upgrading is hard).

Does anyone have any ideas?

**update:** This occurs across applications. In Intellij IDE, in the terminal.

**update:** It also happens when I type `= <hold shift> 2 <release shift>`

**update:** After a bit of digging I can see in /var/log/messages that it's dumped some info to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2012-07-20-10:50:21-1395 and within that it tells me that /usr/bin/Xorg was sent a SIGABRT.

Comment: What program has the focus when you type this?

Comment: Check `/var/log/Xorg.*.log`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, and the output of the `dmesg` command.

Comment: Look in your `Xorg.log` file (probably `Xorg.0.log`) i tried to reproduce it and i enabled slowkeys per accident.

Comment: Hm. You can send SIGABRT to an application using Ctrl-\ normally… never seen it with Shift-[… but maybe something had a key “hung” (I’m seeing that sometimes when I switch virtual workspaces with the keyboard, and one of the applications in focus on the source or destination workspace is VNC, SDL or a VM.)

Comment: Can you provide output of `stty -a`?

Answer (score -2):

Fedora 15 has reached EOL years ago. Many years ago.

> As of 26 June 2012, Fedora 15 has reached its end of life for updates
>   and support. No further updates, including security updates, will be
>   available for Fedora 15

The bug that is affecting you has been probably been resolved in those (almost) 6 years. Probably the core code for that functionality has been rewritten entirely.
Hell, linux ffor desktop was pretty crappy back then, even more Fedora

You are beyond upgrading. Reinstall a modern linux distro

Comment: This question was asked in 2012, right about the time it went EOL. Your makes sense *now* (in 2018), but certainly not then.